# Express.js: Does calling next(error) from a route handler call a global error handling middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling, routes

Let's say I have defined the following middleware and route handlers:

```
app.use(function(err,req,res,next) {
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});

app.get('/test',function(req,res) {
    //some error happens here, and ther "error" object is defined
    next(error);
});
```

Doe the error handling middleware get called?

If not, would the error handling middleware be called if

- the error handling middleware was defined BELOW the route handler?
- I use `throw error;` instead of `next(error);`?
- both of the above are true?

Or should I do something like that:

```
//route.js
module.exports=function(req,res,next) {
    //error happens here
    next(error);
}

//errorHandler.js
module.exports=function(err,req,res,next) {
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
}

//app.js
var route=require('route');
var errorHandler=require('erorHandler');
app.get('/test',[route,errorHandler]);
```

I'm a bit confused right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of middlewares, app.get, app.post, etc. **matters**, they are processed in the order they are added in your code.

So when you define it like you did

```
app.use(function(err,req,res,next) {
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});

app.get('/test',function(req,res) {
    //some error happens here, and ther "error" object is defined
    next(error);
});
```

the first middleware will catch all the requests and returns status 500 so it never reaches the `app.get('test'...`

the error handler should always be at the bottom of your code, so if there's an error in some route handler you call `next(error)` and the error handler will respond to client with some message like yours `res.status(500).send('Something broke!');`

And this

```
app.get('/test',[route,errorHandler]);
```

is actualy bad since you would need to use it in every route

Good:

```
app.get('/test',function(req,res,next) {
    //some error happens here, and ther "error" object is defined
    next(error);
});

app.use(function(err,req,res,next) {
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});

app.listen(8000);
```

Comment: Ah, so next(error) will go into the error handling middleware, even though it is not defined in the route what "next" is?

Comment: Oh sorry it's a typo, the `next` must be in the callback function `app.get('/test',function(req,res,next)` otherwise you get an error `"next" is not a function`

Comment: Will `next(error)` ignore middleware with the `"req,res,next"` signature and go straight to the next middleware with the `"err,req,res,next"` signature?

Comment: Yes it will ignore middlewares with the "req,res,next" signature.

Comment: Great, that answers all my questions. Thanks, mate :)

Comment: I'm really intrigued as to why specifying `app.use(function (err, req, res))` doesn't work (ie the handler is not reached) but adding the final `next` parameter does, even though that parameter is never used

Comment: express first checks how many params you are expecting. so in your case `app.use(function (err, req, res))` you expect 3 params and in this case your err is actualy req, req is res and res is next so express knows this is not an error handler